# Why doesn't this eventlistener for deviceready fire on my phone?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm using Phonegap build, and using the default initiation JS that comes with the hello world example.

Launching the app into an emulator like Ripple and it works fine, with deviceready firing as expected, but launching the app on my phone (Samsung s3) it never takes.

The js is:

```
var app = {
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},

bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},

onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
},

receivedEvent: function(id) {
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
}
};
```

At the bottom of index.html is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
```

Any ideas how to debug this?

Comment: Did u include phonegap.js?

Comment: phonegap.js was mentioned in the index.html, but it didn't exist so I deleted it. Should I have kept it there?

Comment: include same in script tag but at top and check

Comment: It worked - can you add this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include phonegap.js in your index.html using script tag.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I don't know why it works with this when it is a non-exist file, but it does. I guess PG uses this file to populate it with its own data when compiling.